# Show filter choices error on external list in SharePoint 2013

Tags: list-view, external-list

I have an external list on SharePoint 2013 migrated from SharePoint 2010. There are about 1500 items in the list. When I click to filter a text column it gives me the option to "Show Filter Choices". When I click on it I get the following error:

> The "XsltListViewWebPart" Web Part appears to be causing a problem.
>   Method 'RenderAsHtml' is not supported on Microsoft.SharePoint.SPList
>   for external lists.

Any idea what is it and how to fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if the default behaviour of HTML rendering can be overridden for BCS list, however I have used HTML editor to supply filter parameters to web parts before.

Check out [this article](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Use-the-HTML-Form-Web-Part-to-filter-and-display-data-in-another-Web-Part-860b681c-38ad-43ff-a036-a60868497ff7) to understand how you could filter a web part externally i.e. maybe via a value in a text box or through a drop-down.

The concept is, you create an HTML form with textboxes, drop-downs, radio buttons etc. And when user selects various values, they can be passed into your web part `view` as parameter. Now you could go to your modify view page and use those parameters to create filters.

You should be able to pass these filter values into your external list and then filter.